# How to Ensure Xamarin Device.StartTimer runs only 1 instance?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have timer running in xamarin forms application as below and a button click command stops it by _isTimerTaskRunning  parameter false and start a new timer. 
But I believe I have a mistake in my design which is not thread safe and it starts a new timer without finishing previous one. How can I ensure that only 1 DeviceTimer is running here?  I tried Thread.Sleep to wait before starting a new one. it is kind of working but i feel not still not so secure. I couldnt find any method event to check if there is already running DeviceTimer before starting a new one.

```
 this.CompleteTimerClick = new Command(async () =>
            {
                _isTimerTaskRunning = false;                 
                 var success = await RunTimer();
            }

        public bool _isTimerTaskRunning { get; set; } = false;

 private async Task RunTimer()
        {
     sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

   TimeSpan totalPause = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSecs);
  _isTimerTaskRunning = true;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () =>
                       {
                           if (_isTimerTaskRunning)
                           {
                           ts = totalPause - sw.Elapsed;

                              if (ts.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                               {
                                   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                                   {
                                       await DoSomething();
                                   });

                                   return CompleteTimer();
                               }

                               return true;
                           }
                           else
                           {

                               return CompleteTimer();
                           }
                       });

                       }

          private bool CompleteTimer()
        {

            _isTimerTaskRunning = false;
            sw.Stop();

            return false;
        }
```

I tried adding Lock around

```
 private Object thisLock = new Object();
      lock (thisLock)
   {
     Task.Run(async () => await RunTimer());
     }
```

as well as within the timer like below but it doesnt seem to help.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () =>
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {
 if (_isTimerTaskRunning)
                           {
                           ts = totalPause - sw.Elapsed;

                              if (ts.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                               {
                                   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                                   {
                                       await DoSomething();
                                   });

                                   return CompleteTimer();
                               }

                               return true;
                           }
                           else
                           {

                               return CompleteTimer();
                           }
                       });

                       }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a concurrency issue. Use the `volatile` keyword  or the `lock` statement to prevent this. 

MSDN Lock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @apineda please see my updated question

Answer (score -1):

**return true; // runs again, or false to stop**

```
    Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 60), () =>;
    {
        // do something every 60 seconds
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =>; 
        {
          // interact with UI elements
        });
        return true; // runs again, or false to stop
    });
```

Comment: I think it is not what he want. If you open many times using Device.StartTimer there will be more than 1 timer.